# Интерактивная помощь в WPF приложении

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Пытаюсь сделать что то подобное на WPF. На архитектуре MVVM. Может есть у кого-нибудь идеи, или уже есть готовые решения и я недогуглил?[image: Интерактивная помощь]

Comment: Накладывать поверх всего отдельные какие-то представления можно, например

Comment: Можно воспользоваться декоратором либо налепить на коренной `Grid` 4 других, сделав затемнение и расположив так, как показано на скрине, а на нижнем из них создать эту подсказку.

Comment: Почитай про AdornerLayer.